# How to Add a Native splash screen in a flutter app, for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, splash-screen

I want to create a custom splash screen ** Android and IOS** like TrueCuller or WhatsApp or etc., but as I searched there is nothing to do that, anyone can help or suggestion,
Thanks.[Like this splash screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duzQx.gif)

I used some packages from pub.dev, flutter_native_splash,

Comment: I think for native splash screen like whatsapp and truecaller design, you have to design that screens in XML For android and SwiftUi for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this flutter package to change native splash screen easily as you want rather than change in XML file.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Edit: Firstly, you need to design your splash image with the attach of bottom icon. Because in splash screen only one image can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to create a custom splash screen.Declare it in pubspec.ymal

Run this command:

With Flutter:
$ flutter pub add flutter_splash_screen

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

**dependencies:**
flutter_splash_screen: ^1.0.0+6

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_splash_screen

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `branding` parameters in `flutter_native_splash`, that will allow you to add the lower image you indicate in your attached image.